# missing parameter name at index 0 {}

Tags: corda

I try to write a demo - [deliverydemo](https://github.com/CIeNET-Corda/deliverydemo) base on [bootcamp-cordapp](https://github.com/corda/bootcamp-cordapp) and refer [cordapp-example](https://github.com/corda/cordapp-example) for my own Order Flow.
After Party A-C and Notary started by command "build/nodes/runnodes":

1. TokenIssueFlow is worked.
2. I can saw my Order Flow by "flow list" command in CLI.
   But got "missing parameter name at index 0 {}" when try to start my order flow.

---

> Thu Jul 26 09:41:51 CST 2018>>> flow start
>   OrderPlaceFlow$OrderPlaceRequestFlow buyer: PartyB, seller: PartyC,
>   sellingPrice: 12.9, downPayments: 0.1 flow start
>   OrderPlaceFlow$OrderPlaceRequestFlow buyer: PartyB, seller: PartyC,
>   sellingPrice: 12.9, downPayments: 0.1: exception: Could not parse as a
>   command: Method lambda$call$6 missing parameter name at index 0 Thu
>   Jul 26 09:41:55 CST 2018>>> E 09:41:55+0800 [pool-8-thread-8]
>   command.CRaSHSession.execute - Error while evaluating request 'flow
>   start OrderPlaceFlow$OrderPlaceRequestFlow buyer: PartyB, seller:
>   PartyC, sellingPrice: 12.9, downPayments: 0.1' flow start
>   OrderPlaceFlow$OrderPlaceRequestFlow buyer: PartyB, seller: PartyC,
>   sellingPrice: 12.9, downPayments: 0.1: exception: Could not parse as a
>   command: Method lambda$call$6 missing parameter name at index 0 {} 
>   net.corda.client.jackson.StringToMethodCallParser$UnparseableCallException$ReflectionDataMissing:
>   Could not parse as a command: Method lambda$call$6 missing parameter
>   name at index 0   at
>   net.corda.client.jackson.StringToMethodCallParser.paramNamesFromMethod(StringToMethodCallParser.kt:131)
>   ~[corda-jackson-corda-3.0.jar:?]

---

> Thu Jul 26 09:38:32 CST 2018>>> flow list
>   com.cienet.deliverydemo.order.OrderPlaceFlow$OrderPlaceRequestFlow
>   com.cienet.deliverydemo.token.TokenIssueFlow
>   net.corda.core.flows.ContractUpgradeFlow$Authorise
>   net.corda.core.flows.ContractUpgradeFlow$Deauthorise
>   net.corda.core.flows.ContractUpgradeFlow$Initiate
>
> Thu Jul 26 09:38:34 CST 2018>>>

---

```
public OrderPlaceRequestFlow(Party buyer, Party seller, float sellingPrice, float downPayments) {
    this.buyer = buyer;
    this.seller = seller;
    this.sellingPrice = sellingPrice;
    this.downPayments = downPayments;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes, that is a re-build issue.
But, if you are using JAVA for a flow, and using session send/receive/unwarp, this error will rise. And not happen in Kotlin code.

**EDIT:**

I add a Kotlin code just for sending/receiving StateAndRef.

```
class TokenAsk(private val otherPartyFlow: FlowSession) {

@Suspendable
fun askTokenState(amount: Int, owner: Party): StateAndRef<TokenState> {
    otherPartyFlow.send(amount)
    otherPartyFlow.send(owner)
    return otherPartyFlow.receive<StateAndRef<TokenState>>().unwrap { it }
}

@Suspendable
fun receiveAmount(): Int =
    otherPartyFlow.receive<Int>().unwrap{it}

@Suspendable
fun receiveOwner(): Party =
        otherPartyFlow.receive<Party>().unwrap{it}

@Suspendable
fun sendStateAndRef(tokenStateAndRef: StateAndRef<TokenState>) =
    otherPartyFlow.send(tokenStateAndRef)
```

}

** EDIT 2 **

I faced this error again, when I am using Kotlin code.
I have to remove the "private" key word in the constructor of a Flow for avoiding this error.

From:

```
class Initiator(private val number: String, private val otherParty: Party) : FlowLogic<SignedTransaction>()
```

To:

```
class Initiator(val number: String, val otherParty: Party) : FlowLogic<SignedTransaction>()
```

Answer (score 1):

I still do not know why, but that is working after build clean and re-build by:

```
./gradlew clean
./gradlew test
./gradlew deployNodesJava -Poffline=true
```