# Can 3rd party check the state that he does not know, and add this state in a flow as a input state?

Tags: corda

Here is my [deliverydemo source code on github](https://github.com/CIeNET-Corda/deliverydemo).

**My scenario:**

1. A issues tokens to B
2. B makes an order with C
3. C delivers the goods to B, and try to start a flow for retrieving token from B.

**My question:**

- Can C know the state of the token state which B has?
- Can C add this token state in a "retrieving" flow as a input state?

---

As Joel's suggestion, I try to send some request and receive the StateAndRef from PartyB on PartyC in my OrderDeliveredFlow.

Unfortunately, seems like JAVA does not support "unwrap", but Kotlin does.
After I add a small segment for send and receive Java.String and unwarp it in a workable flow - my token issue flow, this flow going to rise this error - ["missing parameter name at index 0 {}"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51529864/missing-parameter-name-at-index-0).

An possible solution that I think, is create a new flow in Kotlin just like "CollectSignaturesFlow".
Otherwise, I have to translate my Java code into Kotlin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C isn't aware of the existence of the token states, so can't add them to the transaction herself.

Instead, C should ask B to send over the token states she wants to spend, and add them to a transaction.

The flow code would look something like:

```
val otherPartySession = initiateFlow(otherParty)
val tokenState = otherPartySession.receive<StateAndRef<Cash.State>>().unwrap { it }
txBuilder.addInputState(tokenState)
```

Comment: I tried to add session "receive/send" in my flow, but I got "missing parameter name at index 0 {}" error when starting up the flow. If I remove "unwrap" line, no this error again.

Comment: I add a Kotlin Class for sending/receiving StateAndRef<Cash.State>, and this issue has been resolved.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to Joel's answer. You could look into adding **C** as a participant of the token state.

e.g. in Kotlin, where other would be set as **C**

```
override val participants: List<AbstractParty> get() = listOf(issuer, owner, other)
```

**C** would then know about the state of the token that B has. However, you can see that this would require the **issuer** or **B** to know about **C** beforehand.

Naturally, the route you take all depends on your privacy model.

Comment: I think, in a real word, C maybe just join in this system after A issued token to B. So, C has not chance to be a party in that token issuing flow. And, this not necessary for telling everyone in this system that B got some token from A, if so, that will be against with the privacy rule of Corda. But, there must be some method for verifying the token is valid.